# Laravel + Angular api not working properly?

Tags: angular, typescript, laravel-5

I have developed web app using Angular with backend Laravel. but in my Angular page did not display backend data. I have following data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient) { }

  getData() {
    return this.httpClient.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/employees');
  }
}
```

but I got flowing error message

```
expected onespace after colon in parameter (typedef-whitespace)
missing whitespace (whitespace)
expected call-signature: 'getData' to have a typedef (typedef)
```

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Those seem to be TSLint errors. You need to properly format your code, e.g. where you inject the `httpClient` you need to add whitespace, like this `private httpClient: HttpClient`. Also for the `getData` function, you need to explicitly state a return type.